# Accumulator is not working as expected -Reducer function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reduce

I dont understand how the accoumulator is working here in this simple reduce function. i  understand accumulator is that after each iteration the accumulator value will be passed to the next iteration, i was expecting some thing like this ...
Any idea please if i am missing something here.

- `Expected output` as i understand reduce function

```
hellois odd // should this pass to next iteration as acc value
hellois odd  is even // should this pass to next iteration as acc value
hellois odd  is even is odd // should this pass to next iteration as acc value
hellois odd  is even is odd is even // should this pass to next iteration as acc value
```

- `Reduce function on array17`

```
const array17 = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function Evenodd(acc, element) {
  if (element % 2 == 0) return `${acc}is even \n`;
  else if (element % 3 == 0 && element % 2 != 0) {
    return `${acc}is odd \n`;
  } else if (element == 1) {
    return `${acc}is odd \n`;
  }
}

console.log(array17.reduce(Evenodd, "hello"));
```

-`Actual output in console`

```
hellois odd 
is even
is odd
is even
```

Comment: The reducer works just as expected, the initial value is used as the first argument of the callback, hence the single hello https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: I think you are just confusing yourself with the line break. If you remove "\n", is the output then what you think it should be?

Comment: yep, but only once, not once for each element as expected

Comment: Thanks all.  but what s the point of using `${acc}` in the return statement `${acc}is even \n`, as its not showing any value in the last three output(if i remove `${acc}` from return statement it only shows  `is even ` as an output.

Comment: or if the `${ }` here is used for the first iteration only and thats why we paste the `${ } ` in all the conditional statement if incase any onecan be true, and then `${}` wont be count in any subsequehnt return statement?